# how to use plugin in c#.net

Tags: c#, plugins

I would like to use a plug-in(for example, ClearCanvas Image viewer) in my C#.Net windows application. How can I achieve it.
I would like to use it with my web application also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEF is probably the easiest solution:

http://mef.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you may use

- MEF
- IoC/DI techniques with scanning capabilities of DI container
- Using Reflection to scan assmeblies that implemets certain `Interface` (`IMyPlugin` for example)